# .Net MVC: MapRoute() using object reference instead of string?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, routes

Currently, .Net MVC enables the mapping of routes using a string, like so:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Default", "{*all}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

My question is, how can we replace the attribute "HomeController" with an actual object reference? Unfortunately, this throws an error:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Default", "{*all}", new { controller = new HomeController(), action = "Index" });
//Error: Unable to cast object of type 'MyController' to type 'System.String'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. There is no overload of RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute that takes a instance of MyController.